# cant catch the correct id to send to mysql database(table)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, sql-insert

I want to insert the clicked button id into my database but I can't catch the correct id maybe there's a problem with my jQuery/ajax syntax or anything else I won't see.

Let's take a look at my code

**PHP Landing Page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#btn').click(function() {

    var btnid = $(this).attr('name');

    console.log(btnid);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_test.php",
        data:   btnid,
        success: function(html){
            $('#response').html(html);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div name="001" id="btn">Click me to send Data!</div>
<div id="response"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The PHP Insert File**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo "</pre>";  

  $hostname = gethostname();
  $ipadress = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $btnid = $_POST['btnid'];
  $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO lovecounter (ip,hostname,id,page) VALUES ('$ipadress', '$hostname', '$btnid', '$page')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('funzt nich weil: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }
    echo "funzt!";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The ajax post works correctly but doesn't send the correct data
When I check my database everything is landing there correctly except the btnid that should identify the clicked button. what am I doing wrong?

> error msg: Notice: Undefined index: btnid in C:\Users...

Comment: try `var btn = new Object(); btn.btnid=$(this).attr('name');` and in ajax `data: btn`

Comment: TypeError in jquery.min.js: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.

Comment: its working [**here, check the console log on click**](http://jsfiddle.net/qeQ9Y/)

Comment: ok now its workin at my localhost host too
thx for ur quick help :) but can u explain why i need the new Object()?

Comment: Assuming you know associative arrays, it's just a way to wrap and send data (value) with a key here the `btn` object's property `btnid` is the key (or index) and '001' is the value. Same thing happens when a form is submitted. it's input data is wrapped in a object and in that object the `name` attribute of the input work as the key for its corresponding user given `value`.